# UK Visa Appointment Refund

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, cancellations, refunds

I had UK Visa appointment today and I visited the office. But unfortunately I had some henna tattoo on my hand (was applied 2 weeks back), so the security lady didn't even let me submit my application as I wouldn't be allowed at the biometrics centre. 
My scheduled date of trip is 1st week of June. Now I dont think I might be able to get visa on time before that date since this tattoo needs few more days to fade away. None of the beauty salons seem to have a solution too.

So now I want to cancel my entire application. Can anyone please tell me if I am eligible for refund? Because I have only submitted application online. I have not yet submitted my biometrics or had my photo taken.

Answer (score 3):

If you have NOT submitted your biometrics, you can cancel and get a refund.

Send them a letter (via the VFS if you used one), telling them you are cancelling with a view towards a future application and now want a refund.

They have up to 90 days to clear the refund request.