# Where can i request for refund of my unfinished uk visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, refunds

I was applying for a UK visa from Toronto. I changed my mind before uploading the documrnt and making any appointments. I cancelled the application in few minutes but they had already charged me for the application.

Now my question is where shall I apply for the refund? I sent an email to helpline they told me to go to the commissioner.  It’s so confusing please guide me, where can I submit a request for a refund?

Comment: You might review Gayot Fow's Answer in this question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47559/uk-visa-appointment-refund?rq=1

Comment: @Huma Khan It might not be the ‘official’ refund route, but you could try contacting your card issuer to see if they will process a charge back request.

Comment: @Traveller that’s terrible advice, the merchant did absolutely nothing wrong here and have an established route for refund requests that has not been attempted - chargebacks are not for this circumstance. I really wish people would stop recommending them for everything, they are for situations where the relationship has fallen apart between the customer and merchant.

Comment: @Moo I worked for a retail bank. It’s one call to them, worth a try although I accept they may say no. Which is why I said it’s not an official refund route.

Comment: @Moo or in situations where the merchant doesn't exist *cough* Thomas Cook *cough*.

Comment: @Traveller it’s one call to the bank, and a black mark against the merchant whether they successfully dispute the charge back or not (neither VISA nor MasterCard like merchants with chargebacks and track their rates against merchants).  And if it’s successful, it may cause issues with that payment mechanism again for the OP if they want to try again (UKVI or whomever may block the payment method).  Thomas Cook style situations are very very different to backing out of a purchase and wanting your money back from a merchant that still exists.